# How can I fix "PHP Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object"?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using [phpInv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpinv/?source=dlp)

on http://alex.piechowski.org/inventory. login=admin/phpinv

I keep getting "PHP Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object"

on line 38 of entry_new.php

```
if ($itemid>0) {
            --> while (list ($colid, $property) = each ($col)) { <--
                    $result = $DB->query("INSERT INTO ".$DB->tableprefix."property (itemid,colid,property) VALUES ('".str_prepare($itemid)."','".str_prepare($colid)."','".str_prepare($property)."')");
                    if (!$result) {
                        $errortext = "Error: property not created\n";
                        eval("\$table = \"".templateget('error')."\";");
                    }
                }
```

Would anybody please be willing to D/L and help me out? I've been working hours on this and I can't seem to get it to work...

It's receiving a posted array.

Comment: You can either make the error go away, by testing if you have an array. Or figure out why your preceding code (which you didn't show) does not deliver the desired array in your `$col` variable.

Comment: But yet, I'm posting my array if you look at my form.

Comment: Just built the array in code myself, but not able to post it by form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue recently.

I downloaded some source from awhile ago and it ended up being my browser.

My browser automatically closed the form before all of the inputs were in.

Try changing to internet explorer if you are using chrome.

If changing your browser isn't working, make sure you're even getting the data you need posted.

You can check all posted values with:

```
if ($_POST) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($_POST, true));
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Wow, major id10t error. After checking the post with the above code, I saw that in chrome (my regular browser) it didn't post. IE was able to post, however. I find this qwerky. I'll look more, but you were able to answer my question. Thanks. Sorry that my question couldn't help the community more though.

Answer (score 2):

if you try to use a variable that has not been initialized you get the same warning

Make sure the variable you try to pass ($col) exists and is not null first. You should also make sure you did not misspell the variable name.

You should try to use function is_array($col) to make sure the variable passed is indeed an array.